# Cipher getting error :: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have following code for decrypting my data in Java but it gives me "Bad Decrypt" error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
     String input = "5H5h8acnv2gzv2PeTVb+pw==";
     String key = "thisismykey___2011_1234567898765";
        byte[] output = null;
        try{

            SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
            output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT));
            Log.i("word is: ", new String(output));
        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.d("myapp", "Error decrypting data", e);  // This is the line
        }
```

Here is the PHP code I used to encrypt the data:

```php
function getEncrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    return base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            $sKey,
            $sStr,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        )
    );
}

function getDecrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    return mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
        $sKey, 
        base64_decode($sStr), 
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
    );
}
$key = "thisismykey___2011_1234567898765";
getEncrypt("Ekram",$key); // After encryption i get this "5H5h8acnv2gzv2PeTVb+pw=="
```

Getting following Exception:

`01-03 10:26:36.930: I/The Text is(911): error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

************* *Stack Trace* ******************

```
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902): Error decrypting data
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902): javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:420)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:456)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.EncryptDecryptTest(MainActivity.java:529)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity$5.onTouch(MainActivity.java:285)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-03 12:06:53.740: D/myapp(902):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 12:06:53.860: D/dalvikvm(902): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 762K, 9% free 8545K/9372K, paused 32ms, total 36ms
```

Comment: When I test this on my machine, I get a `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded` error. Which normally means the key is wrong or the plaintext is truncated.

Comment: Dear Duncan,I have following PHP encryption and then I am decrypting it in Java and getting that error. Let me know what I missed.

function getEncrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    return base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            $sKey,
            $sStr,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        )
    );
}

$en = "thisismykey___2011_1234567898765";
$key = base64_encode($en);
$str = getEncrypt("Ekram",$key);

Comment: I find it very odd that your exception is simply `java.lang.Exception`. Can you edit your Java code sample to show how you are printing the exception? Please also indicate which line in your sample corresponds to the exception (e.g. which line is `533`).

Comment: @Duncan I edited the code above and yes following is the line which is printing the stack.

Log.d("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));

Comment: You should be calling `Log.getStackTraceString(e)`. Please edit your code and your stacktrace once you've corrected this.

Comment: @Duncan Sorry to bother you. From where I will get the log of this stack trace? It's not printing in my eclipse "LogCat" .. :(

Comment: I'm confused. You must know where to get this stacktrace from because you already included one in your question?! Change `Log.d("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));` to `Log.d("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(e));` and update your question with the new stacktrace. Or just use `Log.d("myapp", "Error decrypting data", e);`.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks. Now it showed up. I added the stack trace. Please can you check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check what format data you are passing to `cipher.doFinal()`

I had same issue but turns out line:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

should be changed to

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

and the exception gone. I did compare how strings were being encrypted in PHP and was trying to decrypt it in Java.